# java HttpUrlConnection POST: need to ask for a response for the POST to be committed?

Tags: java, http, post, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to post data on a server using java HttpUrlConnection class. It seems that if I somehow read the response of the server, the post works fine, but if I don't, the information is never posted.

This kind of behaviour is not mentionned in the HttpUrlConnection doc and all examples I've seen of HttUrlConnection ask for a response from the server.

I want to know if I made a mistake in my code or if this is a normal behaviour of HttpUrlConnection, and if it's the case, can someone with a better understanding of how this class works explain to me why it's so?

Thanks a lot!

Here is the code, the commented line is the one that makes the POST either work or fail:

```
URL url=new URL("myUrl");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "myHost");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
os.write(staffToPost.getBytes("utf-8"));
os.flush();
os.close();
//System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode()+" "+connection.getResponseMessage());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `URLCOnnection` class needs a complete handshake for a POST to occur.This means, once you open a connection, you have to readback the response for the POST to actually take place.

Comment: Thanks, that explains things then. (I can't access the link for some reason though, it seems the topic got moved, I'll check that out...)

Comment: Select the first link that is related to Oracle from the search results.Do not know why the links work straight away.

Comment: why -1 here? can anybody explain it? Thanks

Comment: :) Anyway I removed that link because it is not working when I access directly which I do not know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly call [URLConnection.connect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) or get any information about the HTTP response such as [HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29) etc to trigger HTTP request.

You should go through this comprehensive post on [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/945945) for better understanding.

Comment: I don't think `connect()` will commit the request. Getting the response code, message, or response `InputStream` will though.

Comment: Thanks, the link you sent was very useful. I tried using HttpURLConnection.connect() though and it didn't change anything. It seems that I have to explicitely access the response (with getResponseCode(), getInputStream()...) for the POST to work... I find this strange.

Comment: OK, then I guess it's necessary to access the response to commit the POST. Thanks for your answers.